# Maximize with matrices

Tags: matrix, symbolic, maximum

How do I use maximise with an arbitrary sized symbolic matrix?

e.g for a small matrix it is fine to write it out,

```
ymatrix = {{y11, y12, y13}, {y21, y22, y23}, {y31, y32, y33}}

NMaximize[-2*(Total[Total[ymatrix]])^2 - 3 Total[Total[ymatrix]] + 5, {y11, y12, y13, y21, y22, y23, y31, y32, y33}]
```

But how would I do this if `ymatrix` bigger, for example is of dimensions `{100,3}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ymat = Array[y, {10, 3}];
NMaximize[-2*(Total[Total[ymat]])^2 - 3 Total[Total[ymat]] + 5, Flatten @ ymat]
```

> {6.125, {y[1, 1] -> -0.0607683, y[1, 2] -> 0.0892679, 
>     y[1, 3] -> -0.0936603, y[2, 1] -> -0.150047, y[2, 2] -> -0.0840205, 
>     y[2, 3] -> 0.0476687, y[3, 1] -> -0.21559, y[3, 2] -> 0.200936, 
>     y[3, 3] -> -0.000880204, y[4, 1] -> -0.0163985, y[4, 2] -> 0.026977,
>      y[4, 3] -> -0.151111, y[5, 1] -> 0.0385733, y[5, 2] -> 0.139781, 
>     y[5, 3] -> 0.105765, y[6, 1] -> -0.0226961, y[6, 2] -> 0.0591995, 
>     y[6, 3] -> -0.0220974, y[7, 1] -> -0.00234965, y[7, 2] -> 0.0675695,
>      y[7, 3] -> 0.0510284, y[8, 1] -> -0.301971, y[8, 2] -> -0.0280714, 
>     y[8, 3] -> 0.0161941, y[9, 1] -> -0.254097, y[9, 2] -> -0.13867, 
>     y[9, 3] -> -0.147411, y[10, 1] -> 0.0898733, y[10, 2] -> 0.0788414, 
>     y[10, 3] -> -0.0718359}}